# what should a method return from service layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, service

I am just wondering about the way to validate my viewmodel.

A user can own only one team, so I have to check it somehow if he hasn't got one.

```
    public ActionResult AddTeam(TeamCreatingViewModel teamToAdd)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //check if the user has got a team
            if (!TeamService.checkIfUserHasCreatedTeam(User.Identity.GetUserId()))
            {
                //if not then allow him to create one
                if (!TeamService.addTeam(teamToAdd, User.Identity.GetUserId()))
                {
                    ViewBag.Info = "Success";
                    return View("Info");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Info = "It was impossible to create a new team";
                    return View("Error");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.info = "You have a team!";
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View("TeamCreatingForm", teamToAdd);
        }
    }
```

Or would the solution below be better ?

```
    public ActionResult AddTeam(TeamCreatingViewModel teamToAdd)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!TeamService.addTeam(teamToAdd, User.Identity.GetUserId())) //<--- now it is checking and adding (if allowed)
            {
                ViewBag.Info = "Success";
                return View("Info");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Info = "It was impossible to create a new team";
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View("TeamCreatingForm", teamToAdd);
        }
    }
```

How can I report (from service layer) if an error has occured (and what kind of )? In the second case, users won’t know anything about what was done wrong.
And in the first case I have to get an entity object 2 times, what seems to be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can report errors from business layer by throw out param, for example

```
public bool AddItem(string name, out List<string> errors){...}// or just string with error
```

Comment: Yes, if your service code will be used from two or more places(web+api for example). I think it's more elegant then throw exceptions and catch them later.